# dc.js add up only some values in numberDisplay

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

For the numberDisplay I only see examples in which all values are summed. But I would like to apply a filter so that I only see the values for a certain type.

In the example [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/z1vu7534/15/) there is now a numberDisplay where all values are summed.

Is it also possible to only summarize the values of which for example the type is "cash"?

So in this case I would like to see the number 6 if nothing is selected.

Thank you in advance for your help.

HTML

```
<div id="demo1">
<h2>Markers with clustering, popups and single selection</h2>
<i>Renewable energy plants in Bulgaria in 2012</i>
<div class="lineChart"></div>
<div class="pie"></div>
<h5>I want here onlny the total number for type "cash" (nothing selected 6)</h5>
<div class="number_cash"></div>
</div>

<pre id="data">date type    value
  1/1/2020  cash    1
  1/1/2020  tab 1
  1/1/2020  visa    1
  1/2/2020  cash    2
  1/2/2020  tab 2
  1/2/2020  visa    2
  1/3/2020  cash    3
  1/3/2020  tab 3
  1/3/2020  visa    3
 </pre>
```

JavaScript

```
    function drawMarkerSelect(data) {
  var xf = crossfilter(data);

  const dateFormatSpecifier = '%m/%d/%Y';
  const dateFormat = d3.timeFormat(dateFormatSpecifier);
  const dateFormatParser = d3.timeParse(dateFormatSpecifier);

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var tempDate = new Date(d.date);
    d.date = tempDate;
  })


  var groupname = "marker-select";
  var facilities = xf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  });
  var facilitiesGroup = facilities.group().reduceSum(d => +d.value);

  var typeDimension = xf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.type;
  });
  var typeGroup = typeDimension.group().reduceSum(d => +d.value);

  var dateDimension = xf.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  });
  var dateGroup = dateDimension.group().reduceSum(d => +d.value);

  var minDate = dateDimension.bottom(1)[0].date;
  var maxDate = dateDimension.top(1)[0].date;

  //numberDisplay cash
  var all = xf.groupAll();
  var ndGroup = all.reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.value; //6
  });

  //numbers
  var number_cash = dc.numberDisplay("#demo1 .number_cash", groupname)
    .group(ndGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      return d;
    });

  var pie = dc.pieChart("#demo1 .pie", groupname)
    .dimension(typeDimension)
    .group(typeGroup)
    .width(200)
    .height(200)
    .renderLabel(true)
    .renderTitle(true)
    .ordering(function(p) {
      return -p.value;
    });

  var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#demo1 .lineChart", groupname)
    .width(450)
    .height(200)
    .margins({
      top: 10,
      bottom: 30,
      right: 10,
      left: 70
    })
    .dimension(dateDimension)
    .group(dateGroup, "total spend")
    .yAxisLabel("Transaction spend")
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .renderArea(true)
    .legend(dc.legend().x(1200).y(5).itemHeight(12).gap(5))
    .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]));

  lineChart.yAxis().ticks(5);
  lineChart.xAxis().ticks(4);

  dc.renderAll(groupname);
}

const data = d3.tsvParse(d3.select('pre#data').text());

drawMarkerSelect(data);
```

CSS

```
  pre#data {
    display: none;
  }

  .marker-cluster-indiv {
    background-color: #9ecae1;
  }

  .marker-cluster-indiv div {
    background-color: #6baed6;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossfilter is a framework for mapping and reducing in JavaScript. The dimension and group key functions determine the mapping to group bins, and the group reduce functions determine how to add or remove a row of data to/from a bin.

When you use a groupAll, there is just one bin.

With that in mind, you can count cash rows at face value, and count other rows as zero, by writing your `reduceSum` function as

```
  var ndGroup = all.reduceSum(function(d) {
    return d.type === 'cash' ? d.value : 0;
  });
```

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/35p7tk9j/4/).

Comment: Thanks again Gordon!